# Is it Possible to build a complete SharePoint install Template to deploy to different servers?

Tags: 2013, installation, template, share

I have a guy on my team who's is an admin that seems to believe that you can create a complete SharePoint installation template including SQL Instances and Windows Server to deploy to future servers.

Comment: You  doubt a fellow team member? Installation by a human is all key-presses.. so yes, all that can be automated. You have to calculate the ROI

Comment: Its more of a bet sort of thing, so you can build a single instance template with a complete SharePoint 2013 Installation setup ?

Comment: Sure have a look at the template that is used in Azure to build a SharePoint farm. One click and you have a full fault tolerant farm. If you roll it yourself you can use PowerShell to deploy all the servers and DSC/PowerShell to deploy everything you need.

Comment: Thank you, will that work also not having internet access and having to use ISO's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. As we know in Azure we can install a SharePoint farm with a template. But their is a catch that you have to run the configuration wizard to configure SharePoint farm.

- I think, best option is to use the Auto SPinstaller. For AutoSP installer you can customized it according to their need ( what configuration, what service application etc) then save that for future use. Good thing about it you dont need to run the config wizard after words. http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/
- Another thing, i am thinking creating the VM snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm going to do some more research on this, Since I work with the DoD and were having to deploy SharePoint Farms onto classified networks there's more factors involved when Setting up the Farm.  I hope It can be that simple.

Comment: i am sure it will be, but my question is how often you install the SharePoint in that envirnment?

Comment: Depends on which customer/ Organization needs it.  Average 2  Farms a month. not including testing and Dev enviornments

Comment: I think in this case use autospinstaller as starting point as you have to customized it as per you envir